# yahoo weather yql data limit

Tags: html, yahoo, weather

I recently noticed that Yahoo has made changes to their weather service API and was trying to edit the code I was using. I found [this code on github](https://github.com/ikromin/misc/blob/master/yahooweather/weather_yql_example.html) and tried to get only today's weather Info so changed `limit 5` to `limit 1` in variable yql's value, but then div won't display anything. Only after I changed the number larger than 1 (e.g. 2) the div displays retrieved data. I can't figure out what I've done wrong and what else needs to be done.

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On line 27, the code is going to loop each item of the expected array of results. But if there is only 1 item in the response data (`limit 1`), the data won't be an array but an object, breaking the loop.

Here's a quick fix for that (there is some code duplication but it illustrates the idea):

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Weather Example</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" 
   crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <style>
  .weather { display: none; margin: 1em; border: 2px solid black; width: 100px; text-align: center; border-radius: 4px; }
  .weather_date { background-color: #000; color: #fff; height: 1.2em; padding: 0.1em; }
  .weather_temp { display: table; width:100%; height: 1.2em; border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
  .weather_temp_min { display: table-cell; background-color: #efe; width: 50%; padding: 0.1em; }
  .weather_temp_max { display: table-cell; background-color: #fee; width: 50%; padding: 0.1em; }
  .weather_text { font-size: 80%; color: #999; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script>
  var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql';
  var yql = 'select title, units.temperature, item.forecast from weather.forecast where woeid in (select woeid from geo.places where text="Brisbane, Australia") and u = "C" limit 1| sort(field="item.forecast.date", descending="false");';
  
  var iconUrl = 'https://s.yimg.com/zz/combo?a/i/us/we/52/';
  
  $.ajax({url: url, data: {format: 'json', q: yql}, method: 'GET', dataType: 'json'})
   .success(function(data) {
    if (data.query.count > 1) {
     jQuery.each(data.query.results.channel, function(idx, result) {
      console.log(idx);
      var f = result.item.forecast;
      var u = result.units.temperature;
      
      var c = $('#weather').clone();
      c.find('.weather_date').text(f.date);
      c.find('.weather_temp_min').text(f.low + u);
      c.find('.weather_temp_max').text(f.high + u);
      c.find('.weather_icon').attr('src', iconUrl + f.code + '.gif');
      c.find('.weather_text').text(f.text);
      
      c.css('display', 'inline-block');
      
      c.appendTo($('body'));
     });
    } else {
                  var f = data.query.results.channel.item.forecast;
                  var u = data.query.results.channel.units.temperature;

                  var c = $('#weather').clone();
                  c.find('.weather_date').text(f.date);
                  c.find('.weather_temp_min').text(f.low + u);
                  c.find('.weather_temp_max').text(f.high + u);
                  c.find('.weather_icon').attr('src', iconUrl + f.code + '.gif');
                  c.find('.weather_text').text(f.text);

                  c.css('display', 'inline-block');

                  c.appendTo($('body'));
                }
   }
  );
  </script>
  
  <!-- Used as a template -->
  <div id="weather" class="weather">
   <div class="weather_date">DATE</div>
   <div class="weather_temp">
    <div class="weather_temp_min">MIN</div>
    <div class="weather_temp_max">MAX</div>
   </div>
   <img class="weather_icon">
   <div class="weather_text"></div>
  </div>
  
 </body>
</html>
```